# Unexpected output when using default parameters in JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, function

```
function add(x=1, y=2){
    return x + y;
}
console.log(add(y=4));
```

Output I am getting is 6, Why? How does this work?

I was expecting 5 as y=4 and x will retain its default value.

Is there any other method of doing this without using `add(undefined, 4)`?

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have named parameters, you're positionally passing the result of an assignment expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `y=4` sets the (global, in this case) variable `y` to `4` and returns its value, so what you are doing is equivalent to this:

```js
y = 4
console.log(add(4))
```

So, the first argument is now `4` and the second is the default `2`, resulting in a sum of `6`, and as side-effect you created a useless global variable (or clobbered a local one).

The correct way is, as you noticed, `add(undefined, 4)`.

If you'd like to "name" your arguments, you could use a single object as argument:

```js
function add ({ x = 1, y = 2 } = {}) {
    return x + y
}

console.log(add({ y: 4 })) // 5
```

This works thanks to [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). (The `= {}` allows to use `add()` without any argument whatsoever - without it, you'd have to write `add({})`.)

Note that then you need to *always* specify the names.